# Div and carousel based on the number of elements in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a carousel (so with the dots useful for scrolling the images, Next/previous buttons, number text) with the appropriate divs based on the number of elements in the array.

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }

    function myFunction1() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "https://wjko5e2643.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/book/1";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          var id = myArr.Item.id;
          document.getElementById("img1").src = myArr.Item.image;
          var id = myArr.Item.id;
          document.getElementById("title1").innerHTML = `<a href="books.html?id=${id}">${myArr.Item.title}</a>`;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

function myFunction2() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "https://wjko5e2643.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/book/2";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          var id = myArr.Item.id;
          document.getElementById("img2").src = myArr.Item.image;
          var id = myArr.Item.id;
          document.getElementById("title2").innerHTML = `<a href="books.html?id=${id}">${myArr.Item.title}</a>`;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }

    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0
    }

    .img {
      display: none
    }

    img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }


    /* Slideshow container */

    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }


    /* Next & previous buttons */

    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -22px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }


    /* Position the "next button" to the right */

    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }


    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }


    /* Caption text */

    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 50px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }


    /* Number text (1/2 etc) */

    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }


    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */

    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active,
    .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }


    /* Fading animation */

    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }

    @keyframes fade {
      from {
        opacity: .4
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }


    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .prev,
      .next,
      .text {
        font-size: 11px
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="img fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
          <img id="img1" src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=myFunction1();" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text" id="title1" onclick="myFunction1()"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
          <img id="img2" src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=myFunction2();" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text" id="title2" onclick="myFunction2()"></div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
      <br>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

The following example refers to two images; so the numbertext must automatically update based on the number of elements in the array and so the various elements that compose it and therefore have only one "dynamic" div.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Help you with what? Can you [edit] and make it a question with a specific problem? Read [ask]

Comment: help me to make sure that the images in the carousel update automatically based on the number of items in myArr.  Consequently also know how, based on the number of elements, the dots that make up the carousel are updated.

Comment: ***the images in the carousel update automatically*** use `setInterval` function for this.

Comment: I don't want them to change by themselves, but I want the number of images present in the carousel to be inserted based on the number of elements present in the myArr array, As I did they are entered manually, but I don't want me to always update the code every time a new image is inserted. The code must always remain the same and make sure that it automatically inserts a new image in the carousel

Answer (score 0):

You can create element with javascript. To do this, use the `document.createElement([TagName])` method and then append these to exiting element using the `element.append([Element])` method. So if `showContainer` is the `.slideshow-container` element and `dotContainer` the div with all the dots in it, you would get something like

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  let div1 = document.createElement(div);
  div1.property1 = ...;
  div1.property2 = ...;
  showContainer.append(div1);
  let img = document.createElement(img);
  img.property1 = ...;
  img.property2 = ...;
  dotContainer.append(img);
}
```

Comment: but after `div1.property1 = ...;` as well as after `property2=` what should be written? I am a beginner and I would like to understand these things well